# How to select from stored procedure output

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I want to be able to do this:

```
select rows, reserved from sp_spaceused dummytable
```

but I can't because "sp_spaceused dummytable" does not return a table, even though it outputs one as a side effect.

What is the workaround?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could store the result of the stored procedure into a temporary table (or a table variable, or even a physical table) and then query that one:

```
--drop table if exists #temp
create table #temp(name nvarchar(100), rows int, reserved nvarchar(100), data nvarchar(100), index_size nvarchar(100), unused nvarchar(100))

insert into #temp
exec sp_spaceused 'dummytable'

select [rows], [reserved] 
from #temp
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
DECLARE @DataSource TABLE
(
    [name] SYSNAME
   ,[rows] CHAR(20)
   ,[reserved] VARCHAR(18)
   ,[data] VARCHAR(18)
   ,[index_size] VARCHAR(18)
   ,[unused] VARCHAR(18)
);

INSERT INTO @DataSource
EXEC sp_spaceused 'dbo.table_name';

SELECT [rows]
      ,[reserved] 
FROM @DataSource;
```

You can check the [official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-spaceused-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) because the system stored procedure can return different number of columns depending on the input parameters. Your table definition must match the returned columns number and type.

Answer (score -1):

I am not sure if you want to get the output of the SP in your table. If yes, then you have to create a table structure similar to the output of the SP and then use that table to retrieve the result:

```
CREATE TABLE #tempData
(
        [Status] VarChar(20),
        SubCategoryId INT,
        ClientName VarChar(200),
        ProjectName VarChar(200),
        EmployeeName VarChar(100),
        Department VarChar(20),
        ManagerName VarChar(100),
        [Role] VarChar(50)
)

Insert Into #tempData
            EXEC [Your SP Name] [Parameters]
```

Comment: What is wrong with this answer and it is given earlier. Can you explain why it is voted down. ??

Comment: I think that is because of I have given the generic answer and not specific to the user requirements. I think I must have used exact structure of the sp_spaceused procedure.

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out, in future I will keep this in mind before posting any answer :)